# Do foreign debts require special treatment in a bankruptcy petition?

Tags: bankruptcy

To be clear, I'm not asking for legal advice.

I have foreign debts, and I'm aware that while they cannot be discharged in the USA where I am filing, they still need to be declared.

My question is simply if they should be included with the domestic debts on the various schedules, without drawing special attention to them, or if they need to be isolated or declared in some other way?

As this information I am asking is purely procedural and not specific to any case, it should not be considered a request for legal advice.

Comment: Have you tried here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bankruptcy ?

Comment: @RockApe Didn't mean to dupe, but lost access to my other account, I never received a verification email. I will post on Money.SE as well thank you. There has to be a way to ask how foreign debts are filed with a bankruptcy petition that isn't asking for legal advice. Surely that's a question that might come up in a law class or something.

Answer (score 0):

They do have to be declared. There is no differentiation to be made except that the address of the creditor will be outside the U.S. (all debts need to disclose the creditor's address).

> I have foreign debts, and I'm aware that while they cannot be
> discharged in the USA where I am filing, they still need to be
> declared.

This is not categorically true, although there are some cases where a U.S. bankruptcy discharged will not be recognized by courts in countries where the debt is owed.